# MongoDB C# Driver multiple field query

Tags: c#, vb.net, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

Using the MongoDB C# driver How can I include more than one field in the query (Im using vb.net)

I know how to do (for `name1=value1`)

```
 Dim qry = Query.EQ("name1","value1")
```

How can I modify this query so I can make it find all documents where  `name1=value1` and `name2=value2`?

( Similar to )

```
db.collection.find({"name1":"value1","name2":"value2"})
```

Answer (score 16):

I wanted to search a text in different fields and Full Text Search doesn't work for me even after wasting so much time. so I tried this.

```
var filter = Builders<Book>.Filter.Or(
    Builders<Book>.Filter.Where(p=>p.Title.ToLower().Contains(queryText.ToLower())),
    Builders<Book>.Filter.Where(p => p.Publisher.ToLower().Contains(queryText.ToLower())),
    Builders<Book>.Filter.Where(p => p.Description.ToLower().Contains(queryText.ToLower()))
            );
List<Book> books = Collection.Find(filter).ToList();
```

Comment: This should be marked as the correct answer. Thank you for this, helped me out a great deal.

Answer (score 4):

You can use:

```
var arrayFilter = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Eq("student_id", 10000) 
 & Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Eq("scores.type", "quiz");
```

Reference: https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/quick-start-csharp-and-mongodb--update-operation

Answer (score 2):

And doesn't always do what you want (as I found was the case when doing a not operation on top of an and).  You can also create a new QueryDocument, as shown below.  This is exactly the equivalent of what you were looking for.

```
 Query.Not(new QueryDocument { 
    { "Results.Instance", instance }, 
    { "Results.User", user.Email } }))
```